# how to count previous rows with conditional statement in a data.table?

Tags: r, count, data.table, rows, sequential

I woud like to create a new column in a data.table which calculates the number of sequential appeareances of some group. And create another clomun thta calculate the duration of that sequence (is seconds). My data is like that:

```
    minute second      teamId
1:     60     11 Atletico MG
2:     60     11 Atletico MG
3:     60     15     Avai FC
4:     60     18     Avai FC
5:     60     21 Atletico MG
6:     60     22 Atletico MG
7:     60     26 Atletico MG
8:     60     28 Atletico MG
9:     60     30 Atletico MG
10:    60     33 Atletico MG
11:    60     43 Atletico MG
```

And the output should be:

```
    minute second      teamId  C1  C2
1:     60     11 Atletico MG   1   0
2:     60     11 Atletico MG   2   0
3:     60     15     Avai FC   1   0 
4:     60     18     Avai FC   2   3
5:     60     21 Atletico MG   1   0
6:     60     22 Atletico MG   2   1
7:     60     26 Atletico MG   3   5
8:     60     28 Atletico MG   4   7
9:     60     30 Atletico MG   5   9
10:    60     33 Atletico MG   6   12
11:    60     43 Atletico MG   7   22
```

A for loop could give that, however its very slow. My data set have more than 1 milion rows. Help please!

Comment: The first one is `DT[, v := rowid(rleid(teamId))]`. For the second, you can probably do the math using `shift` and standard data.table syntax that you'll see in the vignettes: `browseVignettes("data.table")`. Btw, it's generally preferred that only one question is asked at a time; not a big deal in this case, though, I think.

Comment: @Frank - or just use a simple subtraction - `DT[, c("C1","C2") := .(rowid(teamId), second-second[1]), by=rleid(teamId)]`

Comment: @thela Oh, right. Plus `60*(minute - first(minute))`.

Comment: @Frank and .thelatemail, you solved my problem. I spent ~45 minutos in a loop. With your help, I replicate the output in 2 secs. Thank you guys.